# Python xml generation automatically

Tags: python, xml

I have suppose to save my data which derived from my script to xml. I need to automate it. Think if there is a array so i need to add items of this array to xml as its elements one by one automatically. Is there is any way to do this.

this is my python script used to pass data to xml

```
if score >= 0.4:
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
            predicted_list.append(human_string)
            print (image)
            data_management.create_xml.write_xml(predicted_list, image)
```

here is my xml generation code

```
def write_xml(predicted_list, frameno):
root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "test")

ET.SubElement(doc, frameno, name="frame").text = predicted_list

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("/opt/lampp/htdocs/video_frames/test.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this :

```
ET.SubElement(doc, frameno, name="frame").text = ' - '.join(predicted_list)
```